# File upload node.js express

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload

I am using Node JS as web API server, for the front end, I am using Angular 4, Android and IOS. I have successfully implemented file upload using post request. I am exposing only one port outside. I need to implement file upload with a progress bar. I have only worked with POST and GET requests in past.I am not getting how to implement it on the server and send the progress responses to the front end. Additionally is there any other method that can be used.
It would be of great help if someone could help me with this process

Answer (score 0):

For file upload you can use **DropzoneJS**. Since you are using Angular for front end use [Dropzone for Angular](https://github.com/thatisuday/ng-dropzone).

Answer (score 0):

I was looking into it and heard socket.io can be used to achieve the same. i need to user sharp package on the streamed data

Answer (score 0):

For the server side, I use the built in express routers using multer. Multer parses multipart form data and uses callbacks that play very nicely with express routers.

Then for the UI you need an element that can upload multipart form data. If your using HTML 5 then you should be able to use just about any library that is out there. I personally use Vaadin uploads. It's a nice drop in element that does all the work for you. It even has a nice upload bar and status built in.

Comment: But can we send the client the progress and ability to pause upload? additionally, can we implement data processing before saving for security

Comment: Yes and yes. The vaadin upload allows you to pause stop and cancel. They implemented that all for you. As far as server side. I am assuming your using express. Multer is just another middleware that fits into its architecture. Your free to add your own middleware that does authentication or whatever else you need.

Comment: Keep in mind the two don't need to be used together. Multer and express are an extremely common set of libraries. Many ui libraries and elements work with express and multer. I just happen to use vaadin because I think they create very professional looking elements.